# How to Save datagridview image cell to sql server with c# or vb dotnet

Tags: .net, sql-server, image

I have a set of rows in Datagrid view and these rows have an image column.
I have created a table with field profpic and the type is `Image`
Now I need to save the image column from datagridview to SQL. These images are loading from Web URLs. Please guide.

Here is the code:

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empcod", .Rows(iLoop).Cells(0).Value)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empnam", .Rows(iLoop).Cells(1).Value)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empdep", .Rows(iLoop).Cells(3).Value)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empdob", .Rows(iLoop).Cells(2).Value)

Dim imgCon As New ImageConverter
ms.Read(imgCon.ConvertTo(.Rows(iLoop).Cells(5).Value, GetType(Byte())), 0, 1024)
Dim data As Byte() = ms.GetBuffer()
Dim p As New SqlParameter("@profpict", SqlDbType.Image)
p.Value = data
cmd1.Parameters.Add(p)
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The variable p returns 0

Comment: Dont save image date in the database, store this on a file server where it is supposed to be. Add a link to it in your database, also consider azure blob storage or equivalent. You are asking for trouble in the future https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/07/store-files-in-a-file-system-not-a-relational-database/

Comment: don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)